# Self-sizing tableview cell with only imageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I'm struggling with the following problem: 
I have a TableViewController in which every cell has only an imageView. It uses **autolayout** to cell's contentView's margins and it is set to **aspectFit**.
What I want is the height of cell to size accordingly to the imageView's height.
In the first screenshot you see the white spaces at each side of the first image and at the top (and also the bottom - second screenshot) of the second image.

Note: my images' aspect ratio is variable.

I've already set this with no luck:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

Also this in cellForRowAt:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Any advice is well received.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[Images with aspect fill here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XQhQ.png)

[The constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AYqW.png)

Comment: what all autolayout constraints you are setting for the image view on the cell. please add your xib file image also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create these constraints , aspect ratio here is 3:1 you can change it according to yours , also the real image should have same aspect to stretch completely as you set contentMode to aspectFit

[image]

**Edit:**

If the aspect is variable then you need these constraints

[image]

then hook the height constraint and do this in `cellForRowAt` after you download / get from cache

```
cell.imageHeight.constant = imageRealHeight * imageCellWidth / imageRealWidth
```

Comment: Well, my images have variable aspect ratio. How and where to set this?

Comment: @DanielZ. see my answer. It covers how to do it and why you need to.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I've tried the above but I still have to scroll before my cell updates to fit the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way the image view returns it's `intrinsicContentSize`. I currently believe this is a bug and should be changed. I have raised a radar for this.

When you put an image into an image view with `.scaleAspectFit` and with a constraint on one dimension (width or height).

Then it will scale the image down.

So if you start with an image of 300x300 and put it into an image view with a width constraint of 100 then you will get an image view that is 100 points wide.

However, the image view uses the unscaled image for the `intrinsicContentSize` and so it will want to be 300 points high.

This is the problem you are facing now.

The only fix for this currently is to calculate the aspect ratio of the image and manually set that as a constraint on the image view.

So you might have a line like this...

```
imageView.image = theImage
```

You can add to that to add an aspect ratio constraint...

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: image.size.height / image.size.width).isActive = true
```

Of course, you will also need to remove any constraints added already. Or possibly create the constraint as a property of the cell etc...